# How to read info from an Xbee Pro S2B to an Arduino with a Xbee Pro S2B

Tags: serial, xbee, softwareserial

I am using two XBee Pro S2B modules. One (Router) connected to the laptop via a UART cable. The other (Coordinator) connected to an Arduino Mega with the sketch below.  All I need it to do is turn a LED on and off and display the status in the IDE serial monitor.  I am using Arduino IDE (v1.6.0).

Arduino sketch:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee (2,3);

int myData = 0;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    xbee.begin(Serial);

    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
         int myData = Serial.read();

         if(myData == '1')
         {
             digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
             Serial.write(myData, DEC);
         }
         if(myData == '2')
         {
             digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
             Serial.write(myData, DEC);
         }
     }
 }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have two serial connections. One for the main USB of the board and one for the XBee.

So you need to read from the XBee and write to the serial USB?

I don't know what speed you have configured for your XBee so I have set it to 9600.

This example reads from the XBee and writes to the Serial/USB port

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial xbee (2,3);

int myData = 0;
int ledPin = 13;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    xbee.begin(9600);

    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (xbee.available())
    {

         int myData = xbee.read();

         Serial.print("Data has arrived on the Arduino");
         Serial.write(myData);
         Serial.println();

         if(myData == '1')
         {
             digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
             Serial.write(myData);
         }
         if(myData == '2')
         {
             digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
             Serial.write(myData);
         }
     }
 }
```

Note: Your example also used `Serial.write()` with the wrong argument `DEC` which applies to `Serial.print()`. X-CTU and Arduino both send ascii which is also what the `Serial.print()` does. However the `Serial.read()` just reads the byte so we need to use `Serial.write()` to send the same bytes back to the other end.

You can also make life a bit easier by replacing `xbee.available()` with `Serial.available()`. Then use the Arduino IDE serial monitor to both send and receive. This means that you just use the one USB connection to prove the code.

Comment: Hallo, My speed is 9600.  I copied the program but when i tried to validate and upload i get the following error " C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Print.h:53:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const uint8_t* {aka const unsigned char*}'"

Comment: I have changed the "Serial.write(myData,Dec);" to "Serial.write(myData)". Then i can upload it, but it still does not work. does it matter were the router and the co ordinator goes?

Comment: What does "still doesn't work mean"? You need to provide more info. For example are you receiving data on the other arduino? did you hook up normal serial so you can trace/debug via the pc serial window? What is the code at the other end?

Comment: I am not not receiving any data on the Adruino because nothing is being displayed in the Arduino serial monitor.  I have connected the one xbee to the XCTU program that needs to send a 1 or 2 across to the other xbee/arduino to be displayed in the Arduino serial monitor and opperate a LED.  I do not know what "hook up normal serial" means but both are connected to the laptop.  There is no code on the other end.

Comment: I see. Well one thing to do is to add a Serial.println("Hello, some serial was found") command just inside where you check for Serial.available(). I also suggest you post the code from the other Arduino that sends the 1 or 2

Comment: There is no other arduino yet.  I am doing baby steps.  The 1 and 2 is being sent directly over the xbee connected to the laptop with a UART cable. I have edited my program with "Serial.println"  and Nothing is being displayed in the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE.  So i think it does not pick up the serial port?  But it has the same baud rate and the other setting of the xbee's are correct because i can do a simple chat with them.

Comment: It would help if you were clearer about what is being sent to the arduino and the code you have posted. What are you typing into the Serial monitor?

Comment: Ok, I am typing in a "1" or a "2" into XCTU which is connected directly to the one Xbee 2B.  It must then pass the data wireless to the other Xbee 2B which is connected to the Arduino Mega 2560.  The Arduino must process the data and display it in the Arduino Serial monitor and also turn the LED "ON" or "OFF".  If it receives a "1 the LED must turn ON" and a "2 it must turn OFF".  I am using the program above.  No data is transferred across the Xbee's.  The Xbee setup is correct to my knowledge.

Comment: Saying the Xbee setup is correct is confusing because you are not using xbee you are just using xctu connected via a 2nd usb cable to Pin2 and 3 on the Arduino? You also have the upload usb cable plugged from the Arduino to the Pc? Both x-ctu and the arduino serial monitor are open and both are set to 9600? I will edit the example to show how to add better diagnostics for problem solving. Hope it helps.

Comment: What I ment by Xbee setup, I mean that the PANID's are the same, the DL and DH addresses are set And the buad rate is 9600.  Yes, I have a Uart cable connected to a xbee adapter for Xbee 1.  And the other xbee is connected to a shield (Xbee pro shield) onto the Arduino via a usb cable to the laptop. Yes, both the X CTU and Serial monitors are open at the same time and there baud rate is 9600.  I will appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you done the loop back test in xctu?

Comment: No, I am very new with all of this. What must i do?

Comment: Use the arduino.cc or other forum to learn. This site is not geared towards long running educational threads. Just questions with answers. Or open another question. I think I have answered your initial question.